# EF LINQ - How to query 2 tables associated by foreign key?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

Using EF 6 code first. I have an Entity class and a Name class, and want to query a list of all Entity objects with their respective Names so that I can show on a Gridview control.

These are my class definitions:

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int EntityKey { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Name> Names { get; set; }      
}

public class Name
{
    [Key]
    public int NameKey { get; set; }
    public int EntityKey { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Entity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

In my Data Access Layer, I have a method that gets all entities from database:

```
public List<Entity> GetEntities()
    {
        SdmDBContext entityDbContext = new SdmDBContext();
        return entityDbContext.Entities.ToList();
    }
```

but with this query, I don't get the Names that are associated to the Entity class. I have tried LINQ and lambda expressions, as well as an .Include operation, but not sure how to formulate the syntax properly.

How can I change the DAL method to return the Names associated with all existing entities?

Comment: `return entityDbContext.Entities.Include(e => e.Names).ToList();` Make sure to include `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: Show the code of what you tried. Presently, we have no way to see why `Include` wasn't effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is loading the list of Entities in the Entity table, and with 'lazy loading' it should also return associated `Name` collections when you access them. You declare your `ICollection` as virtual to enable 'lazy loading' because a proxy object will be created to make DB requests when you access something that hasn't been eagerly loaded.

`Include` is just a request to eagerly load related entities by using the navigation properties defined on the object. You can call `Include` using a lambda or string representing the name of the navigational property you want to eagerly load.

For example:

```
public List<Entity> GetEntities()
{
    SdmDBContext entityDbContext = new SdmDBContext();
    return entityDbContext.Entities.Include("Names").ToList();
}
```